# How can I make a specific Heading Level Start on a New Page (article class) ? (Automatically, not \clearpage)

Tags: sectioning

I have a basic article class document with headings to four numbered levels.

I wish to force a new page for every 1.X level heading.

I have tried the following at the end of each and every 1.X section

```
\clearpage
```

This works, but is there a way to automate this?

Comment: The assumption is that `1.X` represents a `\subsection` within the `article` class, so it should be sufficient to add `\let\oldsubsection\subsection \renewcommand{\subsection}{\clearpage\oldsubsection}` to your preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\clearpage}{}{}
```

Comment: it is such a sweet feeling when concise code works perfectly! I can imagine trying to do that in MS Word, think of the time that would have been lost!